# Stripe Checkout - Modal on desktop and new tab on mobile

Tags: redirect, modal

[Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/checkout) claims to be fully optimized to drive payment conversions.

Their solution for desktop involves a modal, so that the user doesn't have to leave the merchant's domain. On mobile however, the same solution opens up a new tab (redirected to Stripe.com).

Any thoughts on why this would be an optimized experience?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*I work at Stripe on the Checkout team.*

Many people integrating Checkout do not have mobile-optimized websites. The reasons for this vary, but a common observation is that there are various nuances for the getting the right viewport.
Many websites using Checkout do not have the `viewport` meta tag; this puts a modal implementation at the mercy of the browser and user arbitrarily scaling the page.

In order to ensure a better user experience that’s not limited by the originating frame, we open Checkout in a new tab. This ensures that we are able to set everything up so that the payment experience is optimized on every mobile device and browser.

Comment: Neat. Modals on touchscreen are almost as bothersome as :hover based menu.

Comment: Hi @mduvall - great to see someone from Stripe answering here, much appreciated. Did you do any research on that subject matter, i.e. that a new browser window on mobile is the superior solution? Would be awesome if you could share insights.

Comment: The main issue here is a user will have no idea how to cancel out of the payment form, the browser back is disabled since it is a new browser window and stripe didn't implement a cancel/close button.

Comment: Is there a way to configure how it is shown? There are situations where a new tab is just not available (eg. many apps using WebView only without dealing with tabs).

Answer (score 3):

Stripe Payments are a painless integration. By that, I mean they are incredibly easy to install/setup/implement for developers. Most other solutions that brag about the same ease of install redirect to a different website on desktop, and do not work well on mobile.

Arguably, they have better conversion rates and more seamless integration than *most* of their competitors. However, you can still achieve better UX through higher level of effort integration. Specifically, by accessing APIs that allow you to create a payment process that blends seamlessly with your website/app.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a security issue, as people are more likely to be supplying payment information over unsecured wireless networks in mobile. Also, modals on mobile tend to be a funky experience, especially when considering forms and payment information. Having someone's account logged in on mobile would allow their data to be prefilled when sent to the external Stripe site.